# Web API - How to post an object that contains a file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm wondering if someone could help, my knowledge is pretty sparse when it comes to webapi!.

- I have a web page(ASP.net MVC) that allows a user to upload a file (HttpPostedFileBase)
- My controller then needs to create an object and the post the object (with file) to an external API (To save the file)

**The issue i'm having is I'm not to sure how to post the object correctly to the api?**

I've a few articles online, but yet I'm still not getting it :(

This is what I have done so far:

```
 public class MediaModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string  AccountId{ get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string EntityId { get; set; }

        public HttpPostedFileBase Image { get; set; }
    }
```

*Controller*

```
[HttpPost]
  [Authorize]
  public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(ViewModels.Client client)
  {

    var media = new MediaModel()
      {
        EntityId = client.Id,
        Image = client.Photo,
        AccountId = client.AccountId
       };

     string apiUrl = "http://localhost:11436/api/Client/Media/Upload";
     using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
       {
         client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiUrl);
         // !!! This section is what i'm having difficulty with !!!
         var jsonMedia = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(media);
         var c = new StringContent(jsonMedia, Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");
         HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(apiUrl, c);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
             //do more
            }
       }

  }
```

*API*

```
[Route("Upload")]
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Upload(MediaModel media)
    {
      //Read model(and do stuff)

    }
```

An Example of what i'm doing wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: what is the response you get from api when debug?

Comment: {"Error getting value from 'ReadTimeout' on 'System.Web.HttpInputStream'."} Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException

Comment: use milti part form data as the content type and make the post. The API should be able to bind the model from that

Comment: Also avoid creating and disposing HttpClient frequently as that comes with its own set of known problems